# Can't install Firebase distribution builds on devices using iOS 9

Tags: ios, firebase, ios9, ad-hoc-distribution, firebase-app-distribution

I have a couple devices running on iOS 9 as that's our minimum supported version.

After I receive the firebase distribution email, and tapping on the download link, I got redirected to a blank web page in these devices.

The same provisioning configuration works OK with other devices, except these two. I verified that UDIDs are included in the Provisioning Profile with a valid Certificate.

Can anyone point out if there's any issues with iOS 9 and Firebase adhoc distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase 7.x updated the minimum supported iOS version for all libraries except Analytics and Crashlytics.

You'll need to stick with Firebase 6.x for full Firebase support for iOS 9.